# Estimator : Mean of ratio of quantities tends to be equal or equal to ratio of mean of quantities

Tags: estimation, means, ratio, parameter-estimation

I have the following estimator :

$\hat{O}=\dfrac{b_{sp}^{2}\left(\mathcal{D}_{DM}+B^{C}\right)+B_{sp}}{b_{ph}^{2}\left(\mathcal{D}_{DM}+B^{C}\right)+B_{ph}}$

I would like to demonstrate that the mean of this estimator is :

$<\hat{O}>=<\left(\dfrac{b_{sp}^{2}\left[\mathcal{D}_{DM}+B^{C}\right]+B_{sp}}{b_{ph}^{2}\left[\mathcal{D}_{DM}+B^{C}\right]+B_{ph}}\right)>=\left(\dfrac{<b_{sp}^{2}\left[\mathcal{D}_{DM}+B^{C}\right]>+<B_{sp}>}{<b_{ph}^{2}\left[\mathcal{D}_{DM}+B^{C}\right]>+<B_{ph}>}\right)$

and conclude, by knowing that $<B_{sp>}>=<B_{ph}>=0$ : $<\hat{O}> = \dfrac{b_{sp}^{2}}{b_{ph}^{2}}$

But I don't know how to justify the equality between the mean of ratio and the ratio of mean with my estimator $\hat{O}$.

**UPDATE 1:**

If I reformulate the definition of my estimator $\hat{O}=A/B$ like this :

$$A = constant_1 + A'$$
$$B = constant_2 + B'$$

with $A'$ and $B'$ random variables.

with the specifications : $<A'> = <B'> = 0$ (for average) and for standard deviation : $\sigma_{A'}$ and $\sigma_{B'}$ both different from $0$.

So, I could have with a first taylor series expansion :

1. $E(A/B) = \dfrac{E(A)}{E(B)} [ 1 - \dfrac{Cov(A,B)}{(E(A)E(B))} + \dfrac{Var(B)}{|E(B)|^2)}$
2. $E(A/B) = \dfrac{constant_1}{constant_2} \bigg( 1 - 0 + \dfrac{Var(B')}{constant_{2}^{2}}\bigg) = \dfrac{constant_1}{constant_2} \bigg(1 + \dfrac{Var(B')}{constant_2^2}\bigg)$

with Var(B') known and different from $0$ and $constant_2$ also known.

3. from **point 2) above**, **could I conclude that my estimator $\hat{O}=A/B$ is a biased estimator ?** since $(E(A/B) - A/B)$ is different from zero ?

**Indeed, I expect the expectation for my estimator** $\hat{O}=A/B$ to be equal to : $E(A/B) = \dfrac{constant_1}{constant_2}$.

But we don't have to forget that first relation is from a Taylor first order exapnsion (Do all higher orders converge to zero ?).

Is this reasoning correct ?

**UPDATE 2:** Concerning the last comment of `@angryavian` below, I would like to clarify some points :

**When I talk about a "true value", this is about the definition of an
unbiased estimator**, that is to say, with $a$ the **"true value"** of random variable or expectation of random variable $X$ (I don't know exactly if I have got to use it with random variable of expectation, sorry) :

$$E[X]-a\rightarrow 0$$

1. **how can I justify that true value of my estimator $O$ is equal to $O=\dfrac{b_{s p}^{2}}{b_{p h}^{2}}$ ?** Is it something that I know **apriori** ?
2. Or rather my tutor has built the estimator $\hat{O}$ from this new random variable $O$ where the true value of $O$ is equal to $\dfrac{b_{s p}^{2}}{b_{p h}^{2}}$ ?

**Relationship between the choice for the definition of our estimator $\hat{O}$ and the random variable $O$ itself is pretty confusing for me** : there too, I don't know if it is possible to guess it easily ?

3. Is the approach of taking estimator and adding to it a noise (in the general sense of noise, I mean a noise disturbing the evaluation of estimator) **a common method in Astrophysics or Physics in general** ?

Comment: You’re asking if $E[A/B]E[B]=E[A]$. In other words, if $A/B$ and $B$ are uncorrelated. This is not true in general.

Comment: @Eric . Thanks for your quick answer.  If we could have a  huge size of sample, Will all terms of higher orders vanish (in the Taylor series expansion) ? I said that since I am interested in knowing the biased or unbiased status of my estimor $\hat{O}=\dfrac{A}{B}$ ( when I say a huge size of sample, I talk about knowing if all higher terms will vanish or not, i.e if the expectation will be closed to ratio expected to be equal to $E(A/B) = \dfrac{constant_1}{constant_2}$ ).

Comment: I don’t understand your supposed series expansion. Is this a function of some hidden variance parameter near 0? If you’re taking a limit as noise goes to 0, then sure, in the limit it’s the ratio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you and others have noted, $E[A/B] \ne E[A] E[B]$ in general, so your estimator is biased.

Under certain conditions, it may not be a bad approximation.
Your Taylor series expansion is a good approach to understanding this.
Restating your expansion:
$$
E\left[\frac{A}{B}\right]
\approx
\frac{E[A]}{E[B]}
+ \frac{E[A] \text{Var}(B)}{E[B]^3}
- \frac{\text{Cov}(A,B)}{E[B]^2}
= \frac{E[A]}{E[B]}
\left(
1 - \frac{\text{Cov}(A,B)}{E[A]E[B]} + \frac{\text{Var}(B)}{E[B]^2}\right)
\tag{$*$}
$$

You seem to be assuming independence, so $\text{Cov}(A,B)=0$. Thus, if the variance of $B$ is small, then the bias of $A/B$ as an estimator of $E[A]/E[B]$ is not too large.

The missing higher-order terms will be the higher-order moments $E[(X-E[X])^k]$ and $E[(Y-E[Y])^k]$ which should also be small if $\text{Var}(X)$ is small (e.g., Cauchy-Schwarz), but this is a hand-wavy argument.

In short, your estimator is biased. But if the denominator $B$ has small variance, the bias may be small. For a more precise/quantitative statement, you'd have to be more specific about what "small variance" really means by reading the Taylor series expansion, and handling the missing higher-order terms with care and/or expanding the Taylor series farther, etc.

---

For my own sake, the derivation of the expansion ($*$):

In general,
$$f(x,y) \approx f(x_0, y_0)
+  (x-x_0) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x_0, y_0)
+ (y-y_0) \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (x_0, y_0)
+ \frac{1}{2} (x-x_0)^2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} (x_0, y_0)
+ \frac{1}{2} (y-y_0)^2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} (x_0, y_0)
+ (x-x_0)(y-y_0) \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} (x_0, y_0).$$
With $f(x,y) = x/y$, we have
$$\frac{x}{y} \approx \frac{x_0}{y_0} + \frac{x-x_0}{y_0} - \frac{x_0(y-y_0)}{y_0^2}
+ \frac{x_0(y-y_0)^2}{y_0^3}
- \frac{(x-x_0)(y-y_0)}{y_0^2}.$$
Applying this to random variables $A$ and $B$, and setting $x_0=E[A]$ and $y_0=E[B]$, we arrive at ($*$).

Comment: Thanks fro your detailled answer. Just a precision : I am in a cosmology context and Variance of $B$ is equal to : $Var(B)=\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}$ with $n$ the density of visible galaxies. So should I conclude that with an infinite number $n$ of visible galaxies (an ideal case with a perfect and impossible to make detector), we could have $Var(B)=0$ ? but in this case, can we say that estimator is still biased ? The ideal case for $E(A/B]$ with $n\rightarrow +\infty$ is equivalent to say that $E(A/B]=\dfrac{E(A)}{E(B)}$ , isn't it ? . Regards

Comment: @youpilat13 The bias is $E[A]\text{Var}(B)/E[B]^3$, so assuming that $E[A]$ and $E[B]$ are unchanging in $n$ (and assuming the higher-order terms also vanish), then yes, the bias converges to zero as $n \to \infty$; this is known as consistency; so your estimator would be [biased but consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_estimator#Biased_but_consistent). (I would not write this as "$E[A/B] = E[A]/E[B]$" though.)

Comment: Great ! it is clearer for me now, I didn't know the notion of "biased but consistent". Best Regards

Comment: Hi ! Could you take a look please at my **UPDATE 2** ? I am still confused about how to demonstrate the true value of estimator $\hat{O}$ and if this is a general approach in physics to consider for example an estimator and add it a noise that disturbs the estimation.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what an "observable" is, or what "true value of observable" means. I'm guessing it is the quantity that you are interested in estimating? I don't think this question is in scope for math.stackexchange, although you can consider writing a separate question here or on a different stackexchange. @youpilat13

Comment: I have just fixed my vocabulary in order to be more explicit.

Comment: The form of the unknown "true" parameter (against which the expectation of the estimator is compared when discussing the estimator's bias) is something chosen by you. For example, the mean of many samples from a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ is unbiased with respect to the unknown parameter $\mu$, but biased with respect to the unknown parameter $2\mu$. Whether you are interested in estimating $\mu$ or $2\mu$ is something you decide.

Comment: Your remark is very interesting. My tutor would have so decided to take the "true" parameter (or more precisely its value) as a special value. In my case, he took the "true" value as $\dfrac{b_{s p}^{2}}{b_{p h}^{2}}$ : this would be thought as a random choice but not really for me. Indeed, he took estimator equal to $\hat{O}=\dfrac{A}{B}$ with $A = b_{sp}^{2} + A'$ and $B = b_{ph}^{2} + B'$ with $A'$ and $B'$ as white noises : is it really a free choice in this case or intuition or something else ? I don't know : what's your opinion about this choice ? it is pretty borderline.

Comment: @youpilat13 [Disclaimer again: I don't know the context of your problem so it is difficult for me to answer definitively.] The choice of the "true" parameter of interest is not a "random" choice, but it is a choice determined by your application. The reason why you care about estimating $b^2_{sp}/b^2_{ph}$ is completely determined by the context of your problem. The reason why you use your particular estimator $A/B$ is probably because the only data you have available are the noisy measurements $A$ and $B$ of $b^2_{sp}$ and $b^2_{ph}$ respectively.